# cPanel Cron to run Scheduled Job Help

Tags: wordpress, cron, scheduled-job

I have spent the last two weeks trying to get Cron Jobs with cPanel run Scheduled Jobs in CiviCRM. Literally everything I have tried does not work as a command in Cron Jobs but when using SSH I have been able to get this to trigger the job to run:

```
wget -q -O - "http://website.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=websiteAdmin&pass=websiteAdminPassword&key=1234567912345678912345678912345"
```

But when I take this exact command that works via SSH and put it into Cron Jobs I get an email stating:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

My next idea was to remove the quotation marks before and after the link, which then failed due to invalid token, the password has symbols in it, so I escaped them using \ before each special character. Then I get:

```
ERROR: You need to send a valid key to execute this file. More info at:http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs
```

At this point, I know for a fact the key is correct since this command runs via SSH and the key never changed every time so far. The escaped characters are only within the password.

I have tried many other things but I figured a log file explanation might be overkill, anyone have any ideas?

Using:
cPanel version 11.52.3 (build 1)
CiviCRM version 4.6
WordPress 4.4.2

Comment: Have you tried escaping also the ampersand characters in the string? ie. `\&pass...\&key...`

Comment: Yes, when I escape the additional characters after the ? I get: 

`ERROR: You need to send a valid user name and password to execute this file`

That was a good idea, I thought for sure it would solve it too.

Using:
cPanel version 11.52.3 (build 1)
CiviCRM version 4.6

Comment: When I was testing this, it seemed that system checked the key before it checked the Username/Password.  You could quick test this theory by escaping things and entering the wrong key.  A return of invalid key would then show the key is being tested first.  This is the reason I ended up having to go to WP-CLI.  I was getting the same type of errors with curl.

Comment: I have been working towards getting WP-CLI to do the job for me and have run into another issue.

When doing this command 

`wp eval-file http://website.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php name=websiteAdmin pass=websiteAdminPassword key=1234567912345678912345678912345 --path=/home8/farrnetw/public_html/`

It returns:

`Fatal error: Class 'WP_Widget' not found in /home8/thing/public_html/wp-content/plugins/image-widget/image-widget.php on line 25`

I did som checking around and all I can find is people having install issues, which is not the case here since this has been up

Comment: Solved the issue, used this line to get it to run
`wget -O /dev/null -q -t 1 'http://website.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=web_admin&pass=web_pass&key=web_key'` but i had to only escape a % symbol that was in the password and not escape any of the other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of anything you are running, or if you upgraded or did a new install.  If this is a 4.7 upgrade, I had similar issues and had to resort to installing and using the WP-CLI method.  If you go that route, you probably also want to take a look at this:
[WP-CLI using GMT/UTC Timezone on cron jobs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/wp-cli-using-gmt-utc-timezone-on-cron-jobs?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry, slipped my mind to include the versions, I might have to resort to WP-CLI, thank you for the suggestion.

Using:
cPanel version 11.52.3 (build 1)
CiviCRM version 4.6
WordPress 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm on the right track here, but what if you created a separate one-liner script with just the wget command you're trying to run and executed said script from cron?

Comment: Good idea, I have tried it, for some reason Cron always reports back saying no such file or directory. I am still trying many things and this idea has not been crossed off just yet.